# How can you save an HTML5 video blob from a URL to a video?

Tags: javascript, html, video, blob

On Apple's iPhone 6 page they use a pretty neat effect that animates a `<video>`'s timeline on animation frame/page scroll. The source of the video is:

```
blob:http%3A//www.apple.com/aa45415d-063a-4fae-b2ad-9cee7764a131
```

Here are some libraries I'm working with to try to accomplish this:

- [purl.js](https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl)
- [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

Here's a JSBin loaded with the above libraries: http://jsbin.com/godaqa/1/edit?js,console

Sidenote: What are the advantages to using the blob file as the source?

Comment: Youtube is also doing this in their iframe api. If you found out anything, please post it as a reply.